# Using the input from one form field to fill in another

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form with several text boxes.

The first input box is "Business Name".  There are several more boxes with various information and then the final box is "URL" where I type in the url I want this business to have in my database.  Instead of manually typing this url I want it to take the value of the title input box, and replaces the spaces with "-" and make it all lowercase.  I also want to prefix the url.

So if I enter "Bobs Hotel", then as soon as I am done typing the URL box would be prefilled with "business/bobs-hotel".  If I typed "Mikes Hot Dogs" it would be "business/mikes-hot-dogs", etc and ready for me to submit the form.

EDIT: I forgot an important detail:
The word "business" isnt actually going to be used.  The word to use is coming from a drop down select box.  This box has 3-4 *option names* (not values), "hotel", "Restaurant", etc.  So if you select "Hotel" from the dropdown then the URL would be "hotel/hotel-name"

One important thing is although you select "hotel" from the dropdown the *value* of hotel is a number, like 5 or whatever (as it corresponds to a category ID in the database)

How might I do this?

Comment: The edit you made is quite drastic from the original question. The correct procedure would be to open a new question.

Comment: Sorry Rich, I'm quite new here, I will make sure I ask a new question next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your inputs have id `name` and `url`, you could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$("#name").on("focusout", function () {
    var business = $("#business").val();
   $("#url").val(business + "/" + $(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-"));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UYfa7/2/)**

**Update:**

Updated the example to take the value for business from a dropdown-list as well. See updated demo.

**Update 2:**

To get the content of the selected option instead of the value, you could do this instead:

```
$("#name").on("focusout", function () {
    var business = $("option:selected", "#business").text();
   $("#url").val(business + "/" + $(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-"));
});
```

Now we get the selected option-element within element with id `business`, and read its content with the `.text()` method.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UYfa7/3/)**

Comment: That works good, but is it possible to grab the name within the selectbox and not the value?  The value in my case is a number but I want the category text.  here is an example of what I am using  `<option value="'.$row['cid'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>`

Comment: That works great!  If I happen to change the dropdown after the title is already entered, then I need to go back to the title and delete a letter and re add it for the url to update.  What would I need to do in order to have the url refresh when the category dropdown is also changed?

Comment: @Jay I guess you could add a focusout-listener for the dropdown as well. Change the first line to `$("#name, #business").on("focusout", function () {`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using jQuery

​

```
Business Name : <input type="text" id="business" name="bussiness"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ /></br>

<label class="url" ></label>

$(function() {

    $('#business').on('change', function() {

        var val = $(this).val().replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();;
        $('.url').text(this.id + '/' + val)
    });
});​
```

**[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/j8jWX/)**

Comment: Hi, I complicated things a bit, please see my edit above.  I need to prepend the the url with the text from a dropdown

Answer (score 1):

A quick `replace` with a Regular Expression and `toLowerCase` will take care of this.

```
var business_name = $('#business-name').value;
var dashified = business_name.trim().replace(/\s/g,'-').toLowerCase();
var url = 'business/' + dashified;
$('#url-field').value(url);
```

The first parameter of `replace` can be a Regular Expression. This one will find all white spaces. The second parameter is what you want to replace it with, in this case a dash.